# How to include 2 pagebles in same method?

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle Db, hibernate, and spring data jpa. I am trying to implement spring batch partition.

I have a requirement which involves doing 2 paginations. I will do first partition, then within each partition, I need to do pagination again so I am not loading entire partition chunk at once.

Let's say we have 10000 records of data in total. First, I will need to partition it in 10 chunks, which is the first pagination. Then for these individual chunks, I need to do another pagination to process that chunk. Each chunk will have 1000 records, do another pagination will result into 100 per page.

My question is is there a way to achieve such behavior? Spring data jpa only allows 1 page able.

Need some guild lines. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a confusion between "partition", "page" and "chunk" terms, so let me clarify the terminology from the Spring Batch side using your example:

If you have 10.000 records to process in total, you can use a Spring Batch partitioned step with 10 partitions (which you called "chunk"). Each **partition** will be composed of 1000 records.

Now within each partition, the chunk size is key. For a chunk size of 100, each partition will be divided into 10 **chunks** (so 10 transactions for a single partition).

Now for each chunk of 100 items, the page size is key. If you set the page size to 10, your reader will do 10 read operations to create a chunk. It is usually a good idea to make the [page size match the chunk size](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L54-L57) for better performance.

So in sum to answer your question, there is no need to do 2 paginations. What you call "first pagination" is actually the process of **partitioning** a step, and what you call "second pagination" is the **chunk-oriented processing model of Spring Batch coupled with a paging item reader in each partition**.